# How to plot histogram for below Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

For example this is the DataFrame

```
      country_code       ($) millions
0     USA                    181519.23
1     CHN                    18507.58
2     GBR                    11342.63
3     IND                    6064.06
4     CAN                        4597.90
```

I want to plot the histogram with X axis showing the Countries and the Y axis showing the amounts on the Y axis,

Is this possible.

Comment: Do you mean like a Bar Plot?

Comment: for hist: `df.set_index('country_code').hist(grid=False)` and for bar `df.set_index('country_code').plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  country_code   millions
0          USA  181519.23
1          CHN   18507.58
2          GBR   11342.63
3          IND    6064.06
4          CAN    4597.90
```

You can plot the graph you want like so:

```py
# Here, df is your dataframe
# Don't forget to add "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" at the top of your code
# if you don't have it already.
# ^ this is for the plt.show()

df.plot(x='country_code', y='millions', kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

This will produce the following plot:
[image]

You can check more about how pandas' plot function works in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

##### Notes:

While Ibrahim's answer also works and seaborn is a great library, I'd recommend using pandas' own plot function if all you want are simple plots like these since seaborn and pandas both depend on matplotlib to draw the plots.
The difference is having 3 libraries as dependencies versus just having two.

Also if you plot doesn't look like this one, you can try calling `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()` to make the image fit better.

Comment: How about if I want to have custom buckets on the y-axis for example 5000000 - 7000000, 7000000-10000000

Comment: You can change the marks on the Y axis by calling `plt.yticks(...)` before `plt.show()`.  
Example: `plt.yticks([5000000, 7000000, 10000000])` will produce a plot with 3 marks on the y axis for the specified values.  
Docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean is *bar plot*, and you can do it with `seaborn` library.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'country_code': ['USA', 'CHN', 'GBR', 'IND', 'CAN'],
                   '($) millions': [181519.23, 18507.58, 11342.63, 6064.06, 4597.90]})

print(df)
  country_code  ($) millions
0          USA     181519.23
1          CHN      18507.58
2          GBR      11342.63
3          IND       6064.06
4          CAN       4597.90

sns.barplot(x="country_code", y="($) millions", data=df)
```

Produces following plot. Of course, further customizations can be made, such as title, legend, colors, bar widths, etc.
[image]

Comment: You forgot the actual line where you call sns to make the plot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have updated my code.